# Passing id's of selected value to different flutter page, sqlite

Tags: sqlite, dart, flutter

I have a sqlite database created and populated already with two tables tbl_genres and tbl_books, and I am calling them in flutter by doing raw sql queries like so..

```
_genreList= await db.rawQuery('SELECT genre_name[] FROM tbl_genres');
```

and placing them on to the page using a ListView.builder, where the page displays a list of genres.

```
title: new Text("${_genreList[index]}")
```

Then, I want to be able to select a genre through the onTap() method, to navigate to a new page which displays all the books from tbl_books within that specific genre. In order to do so, I am trying to grab the id of the selected genre and pass them into the next page so that I can do something like this for my raw sql query on the next page.

```
select * from tbl_books where genre_id = (passed id of selected value)
```

How can I interpolate data to show all the data "books" related to a "genre"?

Answer (score 0):

first:build a new page call it "DetailsPage" and put it in details.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class DetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {

  int id;

  DetailsPage({this.id});

  @override
  _DetailsPageState createState() => new _DetailsPageState();
}

class _DetailsPageState extends State<DetailsPage> {

  final int id;
  _DetailsPageState({this.id});

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    // get the data from db here
    print("id is : " + id.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return new Scaffold(
      // in app bar you can modify the themes, the bar .. etc
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("title"),
        ),
        body: new Text("Details Container ")
    );
  }


}
```

now in your listView view, import this file "details.dart"
and now you can navigate to it :

```
new GestureDetector(
   onTap: (){
     Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> new DetailsPage(id: 5,)));
  },
   child: new Text("id : 5"),
   )
```

passing the id to the next page and then you can use

```
select * from tbl_books where genre_id = 5
```

Comment: So this example is if you hard code the id, i need to make it grab the id of selected value from the sqlite database to pass on the next page... so if i'm listing a bunch of books and need to grab the id of the selected book, its not always going to have the id of "5"

Comment: ok. let assume you are building a list of objects. then you have to make for loop to build all of them, put this   ---   Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> new DetailsPage(id: 5,)));
---- inside the loop and instead of passing 5, pass the id of the object or map or any property

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to ask you what are the columns inside the table `tbl_genres` ?? 
if there is a table named id which i am supposing there should be and also that it contains integer values as per your ques what you can do is pass this in place of 5 in the answer given by @Yousuf Al-Mawali `_genreList[index].id` and you are good to go . 
[Link to his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51412848/7940500)